# braces or not braces in \NewDocumentCommand

Tags: best-practices, xparse

I have a quite specific question and I haven't found it in the documentation 
of `xparse` or in the forum. In the documentation of `xparse`, page 3, there 
are three examples:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{o}{#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\foobar}{o}{#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\foobaz}{o}{#1}
```

in which `{\foo}`, `{\foobar}` and `{\foobaz}` are written in braces `{...}`.

Later, on page 4, there are other examples, but, now they are not in the braces `{...}`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand \foo { m o m } { ... }
\NewDocumentCommand \foobar { m o } { ... }
\NewDocumentCommand \foobar { m !o } { ... }
```

And this is where my question comes in. When is it necessary to put the 
name of the command between the `{braces}`?

Comment: It is not _necessary_. As the argument (the macro name) for `\NewDocumentCommand` is a single token, TeX will treat either the same way. Personally, I prefer the unbraced version, as it looks (to me, of course) better and less likely that someone will try to define `\NewDocumentCommand{\foo123}` when the braces aren't there, as it happens quite often for `\newcommand`...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Hi, so the same rule applies for `\newcommand`, `\def`, etc ... this examples are a little unfortunate at this point :(

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL `\newcommand` yes but not `\def` that can not have braces around the command name.

Comment: Not to `\def`. `\def{\foo}{...}` will raise an error because it's a TeX primitive. `\newcommand` (and family) and `\NewDocumentCommand` (and family) will grab the command name as argument and eventually pass it unbraced to the underlying `\def`. On the other hand, `\def\foo123{...}` will work. The examples mix styles (they probably shoudn't), so you get misleading examples.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik The mix of examples was causing me confusion, with the link given by David Carlisle more than clear, I vote to mark this question as duplicated and close it.